# Removing blocks from configuration files?

Tags: text-processing, configuration

Does anyone know an easy practical way to remove configuration blocks. I have a file in the format:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  ...
}
lease {
  interface "wlan3";
  fixed-address 192.168.0.108;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  ...
}
```

I want to remove the configuration block for `interface "wlan3";`.

I started trying to write a custom grep function but it was getting complex quickly.

This seems like something that might be a common problem. Does anyone have a convenient solution for dealing with configuration files of this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='}' 'NF && ! /interface "wlan3";/{print $0"}"}'  infile
```

The output would be:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  ...
}
```